# Where is APC dll for PHP Version 5.2.11 (on Windows)?

Tags: php, windows-xp, apc

Trying to locate the correct APC DLL for my windows machine. All I have tried so far, causes Apache to crash. Short of compiling from the sources (which I dont really want to do), I seem to have come to a dead end.

Details are:

OS: XP
PHP: php-5.2.11-win32-vc6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest stable release of APC is available here:

http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_apc-3.0.19-5.2-Win32-VC6-x86.zip

Other PECL extensions are also available:

http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the dll in the first link. I get the ff error when I attempt to use it:

[Mon Nov 30 20:08:48 2009] [apc-error] Cannot redeclare class sfconfig
[Mon Nov 30 20:08:53 2009] [crit] Parent: child process exited with status 2 -- Aborting.